# Jenkins is not allowing to create Appium session

Tags: python, jenkins, appium

**Use Case**

I am using Python,RobotFramework and have set of **test suites** which runs automation test using **appium**.  While execution , each test suite invoke a **new cmd** and run appium server on it automatically

the command which runs on invoked cmd is

```
**cmd /K appium -p 4749**
```

All the **test suites** works perfectly fine , when i am running them via **bat** command in **cmd**

```
pybot -V ../Env/envSI.py ../Test_cases/Registration.robot
```

However , when i configured this in jenkins , the appium sessions are not getting created , also the cmd which was getting invoked when running without jenkins is not getting invoked.
I suspect this could be cause of this error.

> Non-existing index or alias 'MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4742): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
>   10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it',))'.

Any way to resolve this ?

Comment: it seems like you are running the appium server in the port 4749 and you trying to use port 4742 in your code. Please make sure appium server is running in the right port.

Comment: @SubanDhyako that was a typo..I have corrected it!!